# Looping through sections of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array containing a large number of contents

```
 Names = ["one", "two", ......."forty"]
```

Now, I would like to loop through sections of the array. For example, from records 10 to 20, How can I go about this?

I tried this approach -

```
Names.each_with_index do |val,index| 
   break if index == 10
   puts "#{val}"
end
```

In this way, I can print the first ten records. What should I do for getting next set of 10 names?

Any help is appreciated. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `each_slice` to get successive sections of the array. For example:

```
require 'enumerator'
Names.each_slice(10) do |slice|
  slice.each do |x|
    puts x
  end

  puts "----"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can e.g. use the [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method:

```
Names.each_slice(10) {|part|
    puts part
}
```